# ¿Cómo enviar correctamente parámetros a un task?

Tags: django

Tengo la siguiente situación, en un signal capturo los datos de un modelo de Django y con esos datos necesito enviar un correo en una fecha específica. Dicha fecha viene entre los datos del modelo que capturo.

El modelo es abstracto así que no puedo trabajarlo en el task, ya lo intenté y me dio error (yo le enviaba al task el id del modelo para sacar los datos).

Por tanto, decidí sacar los datos del modelo en el signal y enviarlos al task de esta forma:

```
signals.py

@receiver(post_save, sender=Ocurrencia)
def notificar_actividades_alarma(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    titulo_alarma = instance.title
    fecha_alarma = instance.start
    hora_alarma = instance.hour
    contenido_alarma = instance.contenido_alarma
    involucrado_alarma = instance.concepto.userprofile.user.email
    notificar_actividad.apply_async(
        args=(
            titulo_alarma,
            fecha_alarma,
            hora_alarma,
            contenido_alarma,
            involucrado_alarma
        ),
        eta=instance.fecha_alarma
    )

tasks.py

@app.task
def notificar_actividad(*args):
    mensaje = 'Usted tiene la actividad ' + args[0] + ' planificada para el día ' + args[1] + ' a la hora ' + args[2]
    email = EmailMessage(args[3], mensaje, 'sipac@uci.cu',
                         args[4])
    email.send()
```

Cuando se ejecuta el task me da error: `TypeError: notificar_actividad() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given`.

¿Pudieran decirme qué estoy haciendo mal? Sé que es algo relacionado con los *args, pero no lo comprendo.

Comment: Hola Ethan, ¿hay algún motivo por el que no quieras utilizar parámetros con nombre? Me refiero a algo del tipo `def notificar_actividad(titulo, fecha, ...)`

Comment: @danieltellez revisa la respuesta que publiqué

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varios intentos y leer mejor, al fin entendí cómo hacer esto.

En mi `signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Ocurrencia)
def notificar_actividades_alarma(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    titulo_alarma = instance.title
    fecha_alarma = instance.start
    hora_alarma = instance.hour
    contenido_alarma = instance.contenido_alarma
    involucrado_alarma = instance.concepto.userprofile.user.email
    datos = [titulo_alarma, fecha_alarma, contenido_alarma, hora_alarma, involucrado_alarma]
    notificar_actividad.apply_async(args=[datos], eta=instance.fecha_alarma)
```

Y en mi `tasks.py`

```
@app.task
def notificar_actividad(datos):
# Sacar los valores de datos y usarlos
```

De esta manera logré enviar la información al task desde el signal. Realmente estaba muy confundido con el asunto de los `*args`.

Comment: Genialísimo. Yo soy más de `kwargs` que de `args`, pero supongo que es cuestión de gustos. Suelo hacerlo así: `tasks.my_task.apply_async((), kwargs)`, y en `kwargs` meto un dict con los parámetros con sus nombres para facilitar luego la lectura. Pero vamos, con respecto lo que preguntabas, está perfecto como lo haces.